# TS1149: File name differs: '/C/..' vs. 'C:/..'

Tags: typescript

The typescript compiler fails with this message (on Windows 10, node 10.14.0) - when started from IntelliJ 2019.3

```
ERROR in error TS1149: File name
'/C/devroot/node_modules/@types/babel__generator/index.d.ts' 
differs from already included file name
'C:/devroot/node_modules/@types/babel__generator/index.d.ts' 
only in casing.
```

So the actual difference is not casing, but the start of the path: `/C/..` vs. `C:/..`

I found some questions regarding TS1149, but none answered my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could fix this issue by setting the `typeRoots` explicitly in the top-level `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    ...
```